# What is meant by "symplectic Fourier transform"?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, quantum-information

I've recently come across the term *symplectic Fourier transform* (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0602001), first page, second column), but googling didn't lead me to any satisfactory explanation of what is meant with this term.
The wikipedia page on the Fourier transform does refer to *symplectic stuff* in a couple of places, but I find most references there quite cryptic.

What is the *symplectic Fourier transform*?

To add some context, in the paper linked above the authors mention that the *Wigner function* $W_\psi(p,q)$ defined as
$$W_\psi(p,q) = \pi^{-1}\int_{\xi\in\mathbb R}e^{-2\pi i\xi p}\overline{\psi}\left(q-\frac{1}{2}\xi\right)\psi\left(q+\frac{1}{2}\xi\right)$$
is the *symplectic Fourier transform* of the *characteristic function* $\Xi_\psi$ defined as (I'm using the braket notation common in quantum information theory here):
$$\Xi_\psi(p,q)=\operatorname{tr}\left(w(p,q)^\dagger \lvert\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi\rvert\right)$$
where $w(p,q)\equiv e^{i(p\hat X-q\hat P)}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the symplectic structure is precious overkill right here, but let's stick to your sources. Let's keep the forms simple, so have mere pairs of variables, $\beta=(p,q)$, as @Kevin chose. Define $\gamma= (q',p')$.

A symplectic Fourier transform is just a double Fourier transform with a symplectic inner product (5,6) in the exponent, so, being cavalier about all normalizations,
$$
W(q',p')\propto \int dq dp ~~e^{i  ~\gamma \wedge \beta} \operatorname{tr} ~(e^{-i \alpha \wedge \beta} |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|) . 
$$
It is simple to work it out by application of elementary bra-ket algebra.

Note this is just a *double plain Fourier transform* of a simpler quantity, which most physicists use, namely
$$
W(q',p')\propto \int dq dp ~~e^{i  ~(q'p-p'q) } \operatorname{tr} ~(e^{-i(\hat X p-\hat P q)   } |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|) \\
\propto \int dq dp ~~e^{i  ~(q'p+p'q) } \operatorname{tr} ~(e^{-i(\hat X p+\hat P q)   } |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|)\\
\propto \int dq dp dz ~~e^{i  ~(q'p+p'q) }  \langle z|(e^{-i(\hat X p+\hat P q)   } |\psi\rangle \langle \psi|z\rangle\\ 
\propto \int dq dp dz ~~e^{i  ~(q'p+p'q) } e^{ipq/2} \langle z|(e^{-i\hat X p}e^{-i\hat P q   } |\psi\rangle \overline{\psi}(z)\\
\propto \int dq dp dz ~~e^{i  ~(q'p+p'q +pq/2 -pz) }  \psi( z -q)     \overline{\psi}(z)\\
\propto \int dq  ~~e^{-ip'q}  \psi(q'+q/2)     \overline{\psi}(q'-q/2),
$$
where I've used the degenerate CBH identity for the Heisenberg algebra going to the 4th line, and performed the *p* integration to get a Dirac  δ-function for *z*, which I then collapsed fortwith, and changed some variables.

Throughout, I've used $\hbar=1$ for simplicity. This  expression for *W* is reviewed, e.g. (128, 139, 143) in our [brief review](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/a.pdf) *A Concise Treatise on Quantum Mechanics in Phase Space*, and was first essentially worked out in Moyal's epochal 1949 [paper](http://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/soysoy/21Moyal49.pdf).

You could visualize this "poetically" as a glorified Dirac δ-function of sorts linking *q* ' to $\hat X$ and *p* ' to $\hat P$, so translating from traces in Hilbert space to phase-space functions.

Comment: ah, thanks for making the calculations more explicit in the edit, that helped!

Comment: Most welcome. To be fair to the symplectic structure, it is not entirely superfluous, as it is unavoidable in the *-product detailed in our book...

Answer (score 1):

I believe it arises as per you definition as 
\begin{align}
w(p,q) &= e^{i(p\hat{X}-q \hat{P})} \\
&= e^{i(\alpha \wedge \beta)}
\end{align}
Where
\begin{align}
\alpha &= (\hat{X}, \hat{P}) \\
\beta &= (p, q)
\end{align}
And $\wedge$ is a symplectic form.

Comment: mh..  I guess that's where the term *symplectic* comes from, but how do you go from $\Xi_\psi$ to $W_\psi$? Or more generally, how is the actual transform defined? There being two variables with respect to which one do you Fourier transform?